# Onclick event shows a redline under it

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html-agility-pack

I am inserting an image in the html document using `HtmlAgilityPack`. But code shows a red line in c# :

```
HtmlNode usern = HtmlNode.CreateNode("<img src='/images/Home.png' alt='home' 

  title='home' onclick='javascript:document.location.href="/Home/Index;"'  <====                                                                                

  style='position:absolute;cursor:pointer;top:10px;left:20px;' />");
```

It shows a red line under `onclick event part`. Can anybody please explain me why ?

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:

You've got quotes inside your string. You need to escape them with a backslash:

```
HtmlNode usern = HtmlNode.CreateNode("<img src='/images/Home.png' alt='home' title='home' onclick='javascript:document.location.href=\"/Home/Index\"' style='position:absolute;cursor:pointer;top:10px;left:20px;' />");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your semicolon should be outside of the quotes around the href value:

```
onclick='javascript:document.location.href="/Home/Index";'
```